# Number theory problem book

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Can anyone suggest me some good book that has problems on classical elementary number theory with solutions?

Comment: Dear OP, you said "elementary-number-theory" but tagged it as "number-theory"! (Not to worry, I've edited the question's tags.) :-)

Comment: If you're looking for more challenging problems, there's the [PEN problem set](http://www.problem-solving.be/pen/published/pen-20070711.pdf). Solutions should be accessible somewhere, I guess. It's not a real book, though.

Comment: sierpinsky's book !

Answer (score 4):

Number Theory: Structures, Examples, and Problems
Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica

Problem-Solving and Selected Topics in Number Theory, by Michael Th. Rassias

Answer (score 4):

Definitely 1001 Problems in Classical Number Theory. You can sample the book here:

http://books.google.com/books?id=Qv8W1Ed0El8C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 4):

The book [Elementary number theory and its applications by Kenneth Rosen](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHh5TMmYXRAhVLuI8KHdEcCc4QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fmf.uni-lj.si%2F~lavric%2FRosen%2520-%2520Elementary%2520number%2520theory%2520and%2520its%2520applications.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFKf025OoCkzoQj6kBM4iytKnY9GA&sig2=4zScf6XveB000aGP2xtrew) is the book you are looking for.

Its solutions are available online.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland & Rosen.  The first five chapters cover elementary number theory and there are hints to selected exercises.

Answer (score 2):

What about "Elementary Number Theory" by Underwood Dudley? I like that book.

Answer (score 1):

The book 1001 Problems in Classical Number Theory by de Koninck and Mercier fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[Elementary Number Theory with Applications](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=d5Z5I3gnFh0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=thomas+koshy+number+theory&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3n9mfoNnlAhU_K7kGHYYsCpgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=thomas%20koshy%20number%20theory&f=false) by Thomas Koshy have solutions to the odd-numbered exercises. The [Solutions Manual for Students](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=aNx8AAAACAAJ&dq=Solutions+Manual+for+Students+thomas+koshy&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdqZjvoNnlAhUeGbkGHXSRC6QQ6AEIMDAB) contains solutions to the even-numbered.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [*Number Theory: Step by Step* published in Dec. 2020 by Kuldeep Singh](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/number-theory-9780198846734?cc=ca&lang=en&) for two reasons. It provides solutions [online](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/) to EVERY exercise. It uses color.

Answer (score 0):

The book by Kuldeep Singh Number theory step by step is ideally for self-study as it provides complete solutions to all problems and video topics with subtitles at the following URL:
https://maths-for-all.co.uk/number-theory/

Answer (score 0):

A. Adler, J.E. Coury: The Theory of Numbers. A text and the source book of problems, Jones and Barlett Publishers, 1995.

J. Roberts: Elementary Number Theory. A Problem Oriented Approach, MIT Press, 1977.

W. Sierpinski: 250 Problems in Elementary Number Theory, Elsevier, PWN, 1970.

I.M. Vinogradov: Elements of Number Theory, Dover, 1954.

You may take a look also at this list:

[https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/literatura.html](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/literatura.html)